# When I use a “TV HDMI to VGA Communication Cable” I keep on getting “Check Signal Cable” on the Samsung SyncMaster 740

Tags: hdmi, laptop-display

Trying to setup my laptop to have a dual screen by connecting from HP 15 to Samsung SyncMaster 740N.

When I turn on the Samsung Monitor is says “Check Signal Cable.” Anyone know how to solve this issue? The able I am using is an “[eforCity 262661 2X Black VGA to HDMI Cable M/M, 6-Feet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002VV1HOO).”

Comment: You need a converter, not just a cable, to convert HDMI to VGA as one is analog and one is digital.  Can you upload a picture of the cable, or a link to where you go it from?

Comment: Bought from Amazon- http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B002VV1HOO/ref=redir_mdp_mobile?ref_=pe_385040_30332190_TE_dp_1

Comment: The amazon product reviewers seem to have encountered the same problem as you.

Answer (score 1):

HDMI is a digital protocol, and VGA is analog.  You can't use a straightforward cable to plug an HDMI source into a VGA port, you also need a box that will convert the signal from digital to analog.

Alternatively, some of the HP 14s have VGA outputs, so a VGA to VGA would work if the port is present.